# secure a riemann dashboard websocket

Tags: nginx, riemann, riemann-dashboard

I want to secure my riemann server/client/dashboard to use it on a production server so that only authorized can access the data.

So:

- I redirect port 80 to 443
- used let's encrypt certificates
- added nginx authentication on the dashboard

But then I noticed that I had to redirect the websocket from the dashboard to the server for the web browser to display something, so I added a port that redirects to the server. This is the thing I am worried about.

I end up with this configuration file (there are probably some redundant parts):

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name riemann.mydomain.io;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name riemann.mydomain.io;

    location / {
        auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

        # note no HTTPS here, that's ok since it serves the dashboard right ?
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4567;
    }

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_session_timeout        180m;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000';

    access_log /var/log/mydomain_riemann_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/mydomain_riemann_error.log;
}


# dashboard websocket
# then configure mydomain.io:4556 in the dashboard
# TODO secure it

server {
    listen 4556;
    listen [::]:4556;

    # not sure if this is the best possible name also
    server_name localhost:4556;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        # note no HTTPS here
        # this is the websocket port my question is about
        # note that it is not directly accessible from the outside
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5556;
    }

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_session_timeout        180m;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000';

    access_log /var/log/mydomain_riemann_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/mydomain_riemann_error.log;
}
```

The only problem that I have now is: the websocket connection from the browser to the server does not look secure (even if it uses `wss`), as there does not seem to be any kind of authentication/token going on.

Am I correct in saying that someone knowing the port and protocol to speak to a riemann server anyone could listen here as well ?
If yes, how would I configure it to only allow authenticated users ? Or is it more of an architectural problem ?